# Ruby strptime error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Weird... can anyone tell me what's going wrong here? Is this a bug with strptime?

```
1.9.3p194 :079 > format = "%m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p"
 => "%m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p" 
1.9.3p194 :080 > now = Time.now.strftime(format)
 => "12/4/2012 1:44:45 PM" 
1.9.3p194 :081 > Time.strptime(now, format)
ArgumentError: invalid strptime format - `%m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p'
    from /Users/fedenusy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb:283:in `strptime'
from (irb):81
from /Users/fedenusy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/fedenusy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/fedenusy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

EDIT: to clarify, I'm trying to work with dates in this specific format, eg "12/4/2012 1:44:45 PM".

Comment: went through the same process replacing Time for DateTime. still not working, just getting a different error: 'invalid date'.

Comment: See My answer and rate it if thats what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minus (-) flag used to suppress padding in strftime is not supported in strptime.

If you trace the Date#strptime or Time#strptime calls from Rails, you'll see that you'll eventually get into the Ruby VM source code for [strptime](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_strptime.c#L170) . You'll see that there is no case in the parser that handles the '-' character. You can compare this with the implementation of [strftime](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_strftime.c#L552), which does have that case.

So, you can't use your format string for parsing. You would need to remove the minuses for it to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this format

```
format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
```

to get:

```
=> `"12/04/2012 02:52:58 PM"`
```

Comment: "12/4/2012 1:44:45 PM" for example

Comment: That has 0-padding. I need no-padding on the day and hour. Which is "%m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p" as far as I can tell. Which is my original example, which still isn't working :/

Comment: 1.9.3-p327 :006 > format = "%m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p"
 => "%m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p" 
1.9.3-p327 :007 > now = Time.now.strftime(format)
 => "12/4/2012 3:03:52 PM"

Answer (score 1):

Date or DateTime provide the `strptime` method; Time provides the `strftime` method.  Right?

Comment: Time and DateTime each provide both methods in rails. I tried the same example with DateTime instead of Time and got a different error: 'invalid date'